# Passing data from recyclerview adapter of activity-1 to viewpager fragment of activity-2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

**my recyclerView Adapter**  - Activity-1

> here i'm sending arguments to ViewPager Fragmnet using **setArguments()**

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("projectName",  jobCardLists.get(position).getProject());
            // set MyFragment Arguments
            DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
            detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobCardViewActivity.class);
          context.startActivity(intent);

    });
}
```

**Activity-2**  which contains ViewPager - Tab layout

```
public class JobCardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ViewPager mViewPager;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private JobCardViewVPAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_card_view);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    //set TabLayout
    setViewPager();


}

private void setViewPager() {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPagerAdapter = new JobCardViewVPAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_home_white_24dp);
}
```

}

**My viewPager Adapter**

public class JobCardViewVPAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
private static int TAB_COUNT = 6;

public JobCardViewVPAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return DetailsFragment.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return WorkActivitiesFragment.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return DocumentsFragment.newInstance();
        case 3:
            return TasksFragment.newInstance();
        case 4:
            return WorkImagesFragment.newInstance();
        case 5:
            return NotesFragment.newInstance();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TAB_COUNT;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            return WorkActivitiesFragment.TITLE;
        case 2:
            return DocumentsFragment.TITLE;
        case 3:
            return TasksFragment.TITLE;
        case 4:
            return WorkImagesFragment.TITLE;
        case 5:
            return NotesFragment.TITLE;
    }
    return super.getPageTitle(position);
}
```

}

**My ViewPager fragment class**

> here i'm getting **NULL** from **getArguments()**

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private View view;
private Activity activity;

public static final String TITLE = "Details";
private String projectName;

public DetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static DetailsFragment newInstance() {

    return new DetailsFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        projectName = bundle.getString("projectName");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
    TextView tvProjectName, startDate, endDate, assignedBy, workCategory, status;

    tvProjectName = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_project_name);
    tvProjectName.setText(projectName);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: in your adapter, You are initializing `detailsFragment object` which has the data. But in your pageradapter, your are returning `DetailsFragment.newInstance();` // creates new object . You are not returning  `detailsFragment object`

Comment: What are you doing dude. you are setting arguments to new instance of fragment. You have to hold the fragment instances which you instantiated with viewpager. then you can easily set any data like fragment.setData("any data").

Comment: thank you,  I'm a beginner in android. i done this viewPager learning from a tutorial, so i didn't care that much. @JyotiJK can you tell me how to pass `detailsFragment object` to `DetailsFragment`

Comment: can you please post code of startactivity() call

Comment: updated my onBindViewHolder() item click.    `Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobCardViewActivity.class);
          context.startActivity(intent); `    @JyotiJK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You can use Single Object (singleton) for your fragment.

In your fragment use,

```
private static DetailsFragment ourInstance = new DetailsFragment();

public static DetailsFragment newInstance() {

    return ourInstance;
}
```

And in your `onBindViewHolder()`, use

```
 DetailsFragment detailsFragment =  DetailsFragment.newInstance();

 detailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

2.Or else, pass data between the activities

In your `onBindViewHolder()`, use

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobCardViewActivity.class);
 intent.putString("project",  jobCardLists.get(position).getProject());
 context.startActivity(intent);
```

and do,

1.in `JobCardViewActivity`,get the string and save it

```
myString=getIntent().getString("project"); //public String myString;
```

2.in fragment, use that saved string

```
tvProjectName.setText(((JobCardViewActivity)getActivity()).myString);
```

Comment: Thanks its working.   but there is a warning at `private static DetailsFragment ourInstance = new DetailsFragment();`  says 
**Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to DetailsFragment which has field view pointing to View); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)**  is that a big issue?

Comment: I think, It is better to choose the second one. since code which makes memory leak is not efficient